# How can I record system calls (including related parameters) of an application from the kernel?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to record system calls (including parameters) invoked by an application from the kernel. Somebody told me I can hook all system calls or hook the sysenter, however, I don’t know how to do it.
By the way, I have tried the strace utility, but it seemed that the strace provided me more system calls than what I expected. For example: I build a program containing only "open, lseek, read, write and close" system calls for a simple file operation, but strace returned me more system calls, such as "access, fstat64 and so on", than those mentioned above. why?

Answer (score 5):

`strace` is going to be a much easier way to go.

The extra system calls you're seeing are those performed by your process before your code takes control - for example, the dynamic loader loading the `libc` library.

Comment: Thanks a lot! caf. According to your response, I rebuilt an application named empty.c as the follwing: "void main() { }". However, there are still system calls captureed by strace, for example: execve, brk, access, ...... where do these system calls come from?

Comment: `execve` is the process changing from a forked copy of `strace` itself into your program by loading the program image. `brk` is used internally in `malloc`, which is perhaps being called by the dynamic linker. Compiling with `-static` might reduce them, but due to glibc's bloat, you'll need to build against another libc like uClibc if you want to eliminate them all.

Comment: Thanks a lot! R... It seems that these "extra" system calls appear at the same place and in the same order for every stracing, so it may be insignificant to my work. I will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try attaching strace to a running process

```
strace -p pid
```

It might be a good idea to run the program, have it wait for an event, attach to it and then trigger the event.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to trace system calls, both from user-space (`strace`) and from kernel-space.  I would recommend starting with `strace` and using this as long as it suites your needs. Moving on to other solution requires greater learning curves.

To address your need to filter the output of `strace`, use the `-e` option. See `man strace` for instructions on using it to limit what you are capturing.